# Apache: 403 Forbidden for WSGIScriptAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, postgresql, mod-wsgi, postgis

I am trying to install [istSOS](http://istgeo.ist.supsi.ch/software/istsos/index.html) following [these instructions from the website](http://istgeo.ist.supsi.ch/software/istsos/tutorial.html):

---

### Installation

Install *PostgreSQL*

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib pgadmin3
```

Install *PostGIS*

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

Configure *PostgreSQL* password

```bash
$ sudo -u postgres psql
> alter user postgres password 'postgres';
```

Install *Apache2*

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Install *mod_wsgi*

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Install *psycopg2*

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

Download *istSOS* and unpack it in `/usr/local/istsos`

```bash
$ wget http://istsos.googlecode.com/files/istSOS-2.0.tar.gz
```

The download location actually has changed to [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istsos/files/?source=navbar).

```bash
$ sudo tar -zxvf istSOS-2.0.tar.gz  -C /usr/local/
```

Set executing permission and owner for the folders `services` and `logs`

```bash
$ sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/local/istsos
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/istsos/services
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/istsos/logs
```

Configure *Apache* and *WSGI*

- Open `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and add the following lines just before the tag `</VirtualHost>`

  ```
  WSGIScriptAlias /istsos /usr/local/istsos/application.py
  Alias /istsos/admin /usr/local/istsos/interface
  ```

Restart *apache2* server

```bash
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Check the installation success on the browser loading the page

```
http://localhost/istsos/admin
```

---

### Problem

However, the webserver returns `Unable to connect`.
When I try `http://localhost:8080/istsos/admin` instead I receive:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /istsos/admin was not found on this server.
```

---

### Searching for an answer

As [suggested by krisfr](https://serverfault.com/questions/588894/apache-unable-to-connect-to-wsgiscriptalias#comment693611_588903) I try to find out why the server responds on port 8080 instead of port 80.

```bash
$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                is a NameVirtualHost
      default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
      port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
      port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
```

There seems to be no configuration for this?!

---

## Update

I extracted [the Apache/Port problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128122/why-is-apache-running-on-port-8080-instead-on-port-80) into another question and received a helpful answer. Then I configured the server to listen to port 80 and restarted the server. When I access `http://localhost/istsos/admin` I receive the following message:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /istsos/admin on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

The owner settings for the folders are set as the instructions tell. I found [alternative installation instructions for istSOS](https://geoservice.ist.supsi.ch/projects/istsos/index.php/Installation) which I still have to understand but I already want to share with you.

---

## Tutorial moved!

There is a [new page for the tutorial](https://geoservice.ist.supsi.ch/projects/istsos/index.php/Tutorial:_using_istSOS)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the server running after posting the problem to the [istSOS mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/istsos). Here is the essential part of the [answer by Milan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/istsos/U0xhVSr4uk8):

> This version of Ubuntu [13.10] comes with a newer version of Apache. In my case I solve the issue configuring Apache and WSGI in the following way:

I post the whole configuration file so it easier to understand. Here is the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` on my machine:

```conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias /istsos /usr/local/istsos/application.py
    Alias /istsos/admin /usr/local/istsos/interface
    <LocationMatch /istsos>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please remember to restart Apache after the configuration change:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you want to access `istsos` admin page on port `8080` ? I cannot see any reference to this port in the doc you provided.

In the doc they say to modify file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. This file is the default Virtual Host configuration for Apache. It is configured on port `80`.

From now, it seems you already have a Virtual Host setup to listen on port `8080`. So, open the configuration file for this Virtual Host and do the same you have done for the default one :

add the following before the tag `</VirtualHost>` :

```
WSGIScriptAlias /istsos /usr/local/istsos/application.py
Alias /istsos/admin /usr/local/istsos/interface
```

Comment: Where can I find the "the configuration file for this Virtual Host"?

Comment: @JJD You should know that, are you the Web Server admin ? Try `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` to find some clues about where port 8080 is defined.

Comment: It is my machine. Nonetheless, I do not understand why it responds to port 8080 instead of port 80. I posted the result of the command at the end of the question.

Comment: @JJD What is the result for `netstat -anp | grep :8080` ?

Comment: `tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN 1804/apache2` `tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8080 127.0.0.1:45608 TIME_WAIT -`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the trail / at the end of interface.
the 8080 is actually the wsgi app(application.py) and 80 is frontend in apache for it.

Comment: Can you please update your post an give an example configuration?